# get maximum number stored in a list

Tags: python, list, numbers, max

**example #1**

```
numbers = ['1086', '1123', '543', '1180', '1222', '1300', '888']
print(max(numbers))
```

*result: 888,
desired result: 1300*

**example #2**

```
numbers = ['1086', '1123', '1180', '1222', '1300']
print(max(numbers))
```

*result: 1300,
desired result: 1300*

**goal**

```
numbers = ['1086', '1123', '543', '1180', '1222', '1300', '888']
print(max(numbers))
```

*result: 1300,
desired result: 1300*

**all 3 digit and 4 digit combinations should be involved**

first 10 results from google index, that offering "enumarate", "max()", "sort()", [-1], [0] also different variations of "for" etc..
got me to write this question.
at most brain dead copy/paste.

---

```
numbers = ['888','999','543']
print(max(numbers))
```

output is the maximum value, if all of 3 items in a list are 3 digits long, but with 4 digits it acts like this.

what is this?

```
numbers = ['888','999','543','1000','999.9']
print(max(numbers))
if float(max(numbers)) < 1000:
    print("hello?")
```

max() function should be fixed.

Comment: You've got strings in the list, not numbers. `print(max(int(n) for n in numbers))` should solve that.

Comment: it considers it as integer till they 3 digits long, and 4 digits it just dodges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You list contains string not integers, you make use of [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) to convert the string to integers:

```
numbers = ['1086', '1123', '543', '1180', '1222', '1300', '888']
print(max(map(int, numbers)))
>>> 1300
```

Comment: we got the winner, after all manipulations ,<class 'int'> on output. and more laconic code.

Comment: max() function should be fixed.

Comment: @kvhrs: `max()` is fine, it does what is should do, but based on types, try: `max(['a', 'z', 'b'])` and `max([1,5,2])`

Comment: no its not, print(max(['1','5','2'])) it skips 4 digit values for no reason, this function sould be called partially implemented logic by bad developers that are part of python development team and don't respect ppl time.
and before reply u should test different variations of whats happening than point that its normal, its not normal and its not a "pythonic way" in any sense.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `print(max(numbers))` with `print(max(map(int, numbers)))`

Answer (score 0):

You could try to convert your string into integer like that:

```py
numbers = ['1086', '1123', '543', '1180', '1222', '1300', '888']
print(str(max(map(int, numbers)))
```

I reconverted the result in string to have the same type as the initial list

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to make use of the key parameter for max:

```py
numbers = ['1086', '1123', '543', '1180', '1222', '1300', '888']
print(max(numbers, key=int))
```

Output:

```py
1300
```

Answer (score 0):

One line generator with `max()` and `int()`

```
max(int(x) for x in numbers)
```

Or

```
max(numbers,key=int)
```